# CakePdf in theme AdminLTE - CakePhp 3

Tags: cakephp, themes, cakephp-3.0, adminlte

How to use Cakepdf in theme AdminLTE?
I can not generate the pdf following the steps of http://www.edsonmm.com/generar-pdf-en-cakephp-con-el-plugin-cakepdf/#cakephp3
Without theme AdminLTE, works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the file src/Template/Layout/pdf/AdminLTE.ctp

On the AppController: $this->viewBuilder()->layout('AdminLTE');

On the controller: $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf');

And on the action Template something like: /src/Template/Services/pdf/export.ctp

It Worked for me.

Comment: I discovered the problem but I do not know how to solve it.
In AppController.php 
  public function beforeRender(Event $event){
        $this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('AdminLTE');
         // Overwrite AppView class
      $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('AdminLTE.AdminLTE');
    }
Removing this line $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('AdminLTE.AdminLTE'); , the pdf works, but AdminLTE has the default menus again

Comment: i dont use this AppView line you mentionate, I use just the $this->viewBuilder()->layout('AdminLTE'); at the AppController and $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf'); at the Controller action. Try that. I remembered that i had the same struggle to make it work as well and now its working this way.

Comment: U're welcome, i edited the answer so you can mark it as solved, so other people that have the same issue can know that